# Adobe Illustrator - uneditable spot colors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, spot-color

I'm editing a file made by someone else (it was a PDF, but I saved it as an .AI file after opening it), and it contains a few almost uneditable spot colors. I can change the actual color (by modifying CMYK values, or I can also convert them to RGB), but I can't change it into a process color (the dropdown box is inactive), and I can't remove it (the trashcan icon is inactive when the color is selected).

The thing is, I need to get rid of all the spot colors in the document, and convert them to process colors. What can I do here?

Comment: My first guess will be that you have a linked graphic in your Illustrator document containing spot-colors? If so: embed it, or remove spot-colors from that document.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I thought so too, but there's nothing linked. The links panel is empty.

Comment: It's been a lot of years since I've seen this.  Two questions.  First, what version of Illustrator are you using.  Second, have you tried making sure that all layers are unlocked (including sub-layers), then that all items are unlocked, and finally, selecting all, and going to Edit -> Edit Colors -> Convert all to CMYK?

Comment: I have the newest up to date Illustrator CC. I made sure everything's unlocked, selected everything, and did Edit -> Edit colors -> Convert to CMYK (there's no "all", and it required objects to be selected). That didn't fix anything, though.

Comment: This might be a bug. See the hacky solution in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/85088/84899). It's for InDesign, but it might work in Illustrator also.

Comment: I found out what was wrong! I was looking at the file and discovered that there were some small objects (just simple shapes) that illustrator labeled as "non-native art" when selected. They were totally non-editable. I ended up removing them from the image, and then I could finally remove these spot colors.